# Chrome extension to autofill additional form elements that appear after selection is made

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, autofill

I'm building a Chrome extension that auto-fills a form. The first field on the form triggers additional fields to appear after it is filled out. I'm able to successfully field out the first field, but am struggling to fill out the sub fields.

To fill out the first field I use this code:

```
document.getElementById('theElementID').focus()
document.execCommand('insertText', false, 'theTextToAutoFill)
```

Here are a few things I've tried:

- Use that same code (updated with the correct IDs) for additional form fields, but document.getElementById returns null because those fields don't exist when the page initially loads
- Refresh the page after filling out the first form using reload(), but it's refreshing the entire page (not just the section after the first field). Is there a way to just reload a section of the page?
- Add an event listener to the class the first field is in (which also contains the sub fields). Wait until that class has been clicked to attempt to fill the subfields. See code below.

```
document.getElementsByClassName('theClassContainingSubFormFields')[0].addEventListener("click", function() {
    document.execCommand('insertText', false, 'theTextToAutoFill)
    });
```

Ideally, I'm looking for a solution that uses JavaScript.

Comment: Those fields are very likely to be constructed based on the value of the inputs filled in earlier.

You can:
**1)** Wait untill the fields appear setting an accurate setTimeout

**2)** Use [MutationObserver API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver).


I suggest the second road 'cause nowaday website are mostly built with javascript appending elements in the DOM on the fly.

Comment: The MutationObserver API worked!! Thank you :)